# How to validator register API nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation

Forgive me for my limited knowledge.
My problem is that I have made the code below myself. When it comes to validator email, address, phone, .., I don't know how to handle it. I have found some documents to read that I do not understand.Please help me!
Thanks very much!

**userService.js**

```
exports.findUserResgiter = async (email) => {
    var result = null;
    try{
        result = await User.findOne({
            email: email, 
        })
    } catch(e){}

    return result;
};
```

**userModels.js**

```
const UserShema = new Shema({
    name: String,    
    date_of_birth: Date,   
    address: String,  
    phone: String,    
    email: String,  
    password: String 
}, {
    collection: 'users' 
});
```

**userController.js**

```
exports.register = async (req, res, next)=>{
var email=req.body.email; 
var password=md5(req.body.password) 
var name=req.body.name 
var address=req.body.address 
var phone=req.body.phone 
var date_of_birth=req.body.date_of_birth 


var data = await userService.findUserResgiter(email);
console.log(data);
if(data === null){
    res.status(200).json({message: "null"});
    return User.create({ 
        name: name, 
        email: email, 
        password: password, 
        address: address, 
        date_of_birth: date_of_birth, 
        phone: phone, 
    }) 
}else{
    res.status(401).json({message: "This email already exists!"});
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of libraries that can help you out with validation. Try something like [Joi](https://joi.dev/) or [Superstruct](https://docs.superstructjs.org/) . Here's a basic example using Joi since it's quite popular:

I assume you're using express? So first I'm gonna write some middleware that checks the req.body against a schema:

```
export function validateResource(schema) {
 return (req, res, next) => {
  try {
   schema.validate(req.body);
   //move to next middleware if validation success
   next();
  }
  catch(err) {
   //pass to an error handling middleware
   next(err);
   //or send bad request status code
   res.sendStatus(400);
  }
}
```

Then define your schema:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const userSchema = Joi.object({

 name: Joi.string().required(),    
 email: Joi.string().email().required(),  
 password: Joi.string().required(),
 //etc.... refer to the docs for other validation methods, there are loads
});
```

Use the middleware like so:

```
//require your userSchema

app.post("/some_endpoint", validateResource(userSchema), (req, res, next) => {
 //at this point in the code, the data is validated
}
```

You can reuse the validateResource middleware with any schema you define.